# ROS1 melodic - Setting up openzen sensor (IMU)

Tags: ros-melodic, ubuntu, sensor, sensor-error

I have ROS1 melodic installed. (http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu)

I have an imu sensor connected to my computer through an USB port and I want to use OpenZen's **openzen_sensor** ROS package to access the sensor's data.

Things I have tried:

**1. I followed first the installing instructions available on ROS's website (http://wiki.ros.org/openzen_sensor)**

After following the installation steps I was faced with the following error message:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-HP-EliteDesk-800-G1-SFF:~$ rosrun openzen_sensor openzen_sensor_node 
[ INFO] [1702389265.013190189]: OpenZen sensors will be listed
[ INFO] [1702389265.014809048]: OpenZen sensor with name LPMSRS3B003B0027 on IO system LinuxDevice found
[ INFO] [1702389265.014842222]: Connecting to found sensor LPMSRS3B003B0027 on IO system LinuxDevice
[ERROR] [1702389268.367975798]: Cannot connect to sensor found with discovery. Make sure you have the user rights to access serial devices.
[ERROR] [1702389268.368145912]: OpenZen sensor could not be connected
```

**2. Problemsolving attempt**
After browsing a couple of forums I have realized that I glossed over a step which was not present in the ROS documentation and only could be found in the package's bitbucket repo (https://index.ros.org/p/openzen_sensor/bitbucket-lpresearch-openzenros/#melodic).
The step I have missed is adding my user to the dialout group, so I added it:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-HP-EliteDesk-800-G1-SFF:~$ sudo adduser ubuntu dialout
```

However this did not help, and I was facing the same error message again.

Now I am completely stuck and don't know how to resolve this problem.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

My setup:
I have dualboot with windows 10 and ubuntu on separate hard drives.
Ubuntu version:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-HP-EliteDesk-800-G1-SFF:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```